How to Convert a Byte Array to Unsigned Short and Calculate Standby Time from Battery Current in Android?
I'm working on an Android project where I need to interpret a byte array representing the battery current in mA and calculate the remaining standby time based on the battery capacity.
Currently, I receive the battery current as a byte array in the format [-14, -5], which corresponds to a 16-bit signed integer. The battery capacity is 12800 mAh.
My goal is to:

Correctly convert the byte array to an unsigned short (16-bit
integer).

Use this value to calculate the remaining standby time in
hours and minutes.


And finally i have to display the value as hours & minutes.
Note : i am using a custom service UUID along with the Char UUID

Since you are using a custom service it seems like you are the one that provides these values as a byte array, are you not?

Actually client have not provided much info about the mapping data, but this is working fine in IOS app, i need to manage somehow in Android. That is the challenging part for me. Unfortunately there is no contact with the IOS developer as well. So i dont have any other option

There is not much we can do for custom implementations without seeing the code unfortunately... Do you know which value of battery current produced the output of [-14, -5]? Also, could you provide the two values in hex format?

I will only help you with converting byte array into an integer. And then you can use linear interpolation to convert the capacity value to remaining time value.
By the way it is easier to process byte arrays in iOS because it supports unsigned types like UInt8. But unfortunately the Android ecosystem does not support unsigned types.
However you can still convert the bytes using the int type without loss. You can also do the opposite if you'd like to.
Before you dive into the codes, I recommend you to get familiar with what endianness is. Because handling raw data cross devices requires some background on endianness. Other wise the data formed from raw might be corrupt.
Convert 16 bit Raw Value into an int in Little Endian Format
byte[] received = /* You get this value from bluetooth callbacks */
int converted16Bit = 0;
converted16Bit = received[0] & 0xFF;
converted16Bit |= (received[1] & 0xFF) << 8;
// There you have the 16 bit sent value in converted16Bit in Little Endian format

Convert 16 bit Raw Value into an int in Big Endian Format
byte[] received = /* You get this value from bluetooth callbacks */
int converted16Bit = 0;
converted16Bit = (received[0] & 0xFF) << 8;
converted16Bit |= received[1] & 0xFF;
// There you have the 16 bit sent value in converted16Bit in Big Endian format

So we simply used bit operatins to build up the value from raw data. Remember everything in digital world is made up of bits.
